# Extract email field from 'User' model and add it to a seperate model 'Email' via foreign key

Tags: php, laravel, user-registration

I'm pretty new to Laravel and was instructed to seperate the field 'email' from the 'User' model and instead use an foreign_id that corresponds with a newly created model 'Email'.

Users:

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id();
        $table->integer('email_id');
        $table->string('password');
        $table->rememberToken();
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

Emails:

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('emails', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id();
        $table->string('email')->unique();
        $table->timestamp('email_verified_at')->nullable();
        $table->boolean('is_active')->default(True);
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

Of course I've already set the relations in those models.

Now when a new user registers via form I want to check whether the entered mail address already exists in the 'emails' table and whether the mail address that might have been found has the property 'is_active' set to true.

Currently the 'validator' and 'create' functions in the RegisterController are pretty basic:

```
/**
 * Get a validator for an incoming registration request.
 *
 * @param  array  $data
 * @return \Illuminate\Contracts\Validation\Validator
 */
protected function validator(array $data)
{
    return Validator::make($data, [
        'name' => ['required', 'string', 'max:255'],
        'email' => ['required', 'string', 'email', 'max:255', 'unique:users'],
        'password' => ['required', 'string', 'min:8', 'confirmed'],
    ]);
}

/**
 * Create a new user instance after a valid registration.
 *
 * @param  array  $data
 * @return \App\User
 */
protected function create(array $data)
{
    return User::create([
        'name' => $data['name'],
        'email' => $data['email'],
        'password' => Hash::make($data['password']),
    ]);
}
```

Is there a way to accomplish this in a sensible way? And also are there other files that would have to be adapted in order for this to work properly?

Greetings,
Frame

Comment: I'm curious - What's the purpose of having the emails in a separate table?

Comment: If you only had to check if the email is already there, you could use the [exists validation rule](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/validation#rule-exists). For the second part you'll have to write a [custom validation rule](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/validation#custom-validation-rules)

Comment: my supervisor wanted me put it into a seperate table because there are several types of users that are handled in different models and migrations. But the mail addresses should still be unique

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you want to check that there should not exist an email in the database which is active, you need to use `unique` validation rule.
https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/validation#rule-unique

```
use Illuminate\Validation\Rule;
```

Add this rule in your the rules.

```
'email' => ['required', 'string', 'email', 'max:255', Rule::unique('emails', 
             'email')->where(function($query) {
              return $query->where('is_active', TRUE);
           })
],
```

Controller

```
protected function create(array $data)
{
    $email = Email::create([
          'email' => $data['email']
    ]);

    return User::create([
        'email_id' => $email->id,
        'password' => Hash::make($data['password']),
    ]);
}
```

Comment: your example perfectly checks whether the email address already exists in the 'Emails' table.
As a php newbie a still have problems with actually adding the validated mail address into the 'Emails' table and adding the corresponding id into the 'Users' table. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Yeah, sure :) If it's something small, mention it here in the comments or update the post. Otherwise, create another post I'll look into it, and I'm sure there will be other people to respond as well. So don't worry :)

Comment: `adding the validated mail address into the 'Emails' table and adding the corresponding id into the 'Users' table` . Shall I add the create statements? Let me know what you need help with.

Comment: that would be great. Thanks!

Comment: The relation between email and users should be one to many, right? (based on the comment you mentioned in your post).  `there are several types of users that are handled in different models and migrations. But the mail addresses should still be unique `

Comment: I've updated the answer. In case the solution solved your problem, acceptance of the answer is desirable :)